# Ограничить результаты обратного геокодирования большими городами

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, геолокация, geocoding, yandex-geocoding-api

Задача найти ближайший крупный город по координатам, Yandex API справляется на ура, только выдает с очень большой точностью, то есть хутора, поселки, мелкие города.  Мне нужно получить самый ближайший большой город.
Есть ли возможность задать это через параметры запроса, я посмотрел документацию подобного не нашел(есть только точность для поиска дома).
Вот пример ответа

```
"Address" => "Россия, Оренбургская область, Оренбургский район, хутор Медовка"
      "CountryNameCode" => "RU"
      "CountryName" => "Россия"
      "AdministrativeAreaName" => "Оренбургская область"
      "SubAdministrativeAreaName" => "Оренбургский район"
      "LocalityName" => "хутор Медовка"
      "Longitude" => 55.342635
      "Latitude" => 51.811496
```

Кроме этого в ответе еще присутсвуют несколько объектов среди них и сам Оренбург, то есть при данном запросе нужно выводить только Оренбург(самый большой населенный пункт, областной центр).

Скажите есть ли какая-то возможность задать это через фильтры АПИ, не важно то ли карты Яндекса, Google.
Или только вариант в данном случае брать область AdministrativeAreaName и искать среди остальных ответов где LocalityName начинается также как область ?

Подскажите пожалуйста какие есть варианты для таких нужд или придется выдумывать свой велосипед.

Comment: Вы уже нашли правильную идею. Нужно только реализовать. Да, это будет два запроса к геокодеру, но других вариантов нет (по крайней мере в текущей версии)

Comment: @Crosp еще есть базы [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/)

Answer (score 1):

В Геокодере есть [параметр `kind`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/?from=SO), который определяет вид топонима при обратном геокодировании (по координатам). Для поиска ближайшего населенного пункта нужно значение locality.

При использовании HTTP Геокодера он указывается так:

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=27.525773,53.89079&kind=locality
```

При использовании JS API `kind` [задается](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geocode-docpage/?from=SO#param-options.kind) при вызове функции `geocode()`.